# How to make a JTable non-editable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to make a `JTable` non-editable? I don't want my users to be able to edit the values in cells by double-clicking them.

Comment: Much better answer available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919230/disable-user-edit-in-jtable

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html).

Define a class like this:

```
public class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    //not necessary
}
```

actually `isCellEditable()` is `false` by default so you may omit it. (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html)

Then use the `setModel()` method of your `JTable`.

```
JTable myTable = new JTable();
myTable.setModel(new MyModel());
```

Comment: You can't have a `public void` method return a boolean.

Comment: Also the method is `isCellEditable`

Comment: While the approach you specify works, there is no such method as isEditable in the AbstractTableModel. What exists is the method isCellEditable(int,int) which takes rowIndex and coulmnIndex as parameters. The user can selectively enable/disable editing for a particular row/column by overriding "isCellEditable" method or can use the default implementation to disable editing for all cells.

Answer (score 170):

You can override the method isCellEditable and implement as you want
for example:

```
//instance table model
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
       //all cells false
       return false;
    }
};

table.setModel(tableModel);
```

or

```
//instance table model
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {

   @Override
   public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
       //Only the third column
       return column == 3;
   }
};

table.setModel(tableModel);
```

*Note for if your JTable disappears*

If your `JTable` is disappearing when you use this it is most likely because you need to use the [`DefaultTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel-java.lang.Object:A:A-java.lang.Object:A-) constructor instead.

```
//instance table model
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
       //all cells false
       return false;
    }
};

table.setModel(tableModel);
```

Comment: This is the most simple solution indeed for someone who just wants a default table model, only not editable.

Comment: This is also the solution for making double click events work correctly with JTable.  A double click is normally consumed by a cell as it goes into edit mode, and this will keep a cell from doing that and instead send the double click to the JTable itself.  Thanks for the solution, Nelson!

Comment: @Jop then something is wrong elsewhere in your code - a table _never_ disappears just because the table's model is not editable ...

Comment: Isn't they way the isCellEditable written supposed to return a true or false value and not return column == 3.

Comment: @DougHauf it appears you don't know Java, or really any language that well since most languages use the same-ish syntax for boolean operations...that does return a boolean...I would recommend you go find a very basic Java tutorial and start from the beginning. Trying to jump into swing like this is going to end up with you learning everything wrong.

Comment: @DougHauf, the == is an alias for the Equals function that compare the objects (on the left and the right) and returns a boolean. I suppose you have used the statement if that evaluates booleans and usually is used with this kind of expressions for example if(a == b) do something. Try to print a==b or just assign this for a variable and understand the result.

Comment: The above fix doesn't work for me either.  It causes  the table's column and data elements to disappear. My table is created with table = new JTable(tempTable, columnNames);, where tempTable is a String[][] and Column Names is a String[]. I believe the issue is caused by new DefaultTableModel() not specifying the data and column names for the table model.  How do I specify those in the data model.  I tried table.setModel (tableModel(tempTable, columnNames));, but that causes a "can not find symbol" error.

Answer (score 77):

```
table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);
```

Comment: This is the best and easiest answer. Of course, you have to set the editor to null so you won't be able to edit it.

Comment: This works great with single selection. Wich was my requierement.

Comment: This should be the ANSWER!

Answer (score 43):

just add

```
table.setEnabled(false);
```

it works fine for me.

Comment: This is great if you're not using a custom table model!

Comment: But you won't be able to select a cell or row.

Comment: This will look "greyed out" in some L&F's.

Comment: This is the simplest solution to what I understand the initial question to be asking. With regard to the inability to select cells and rows, would `setCellSelectionEnabled()` help? 

I suspect that the disabled default cell colors could be overridden at the very least with `setOpaque(false)` and using the containing JPanel background color.

Comment: That works. Thanks.  However, I would still like to know why nelson's data model method causes the table's column and data elements to disapper.

Comment: Works well for me!

Comment: @WillNielsen This is the worst solution. It should have negative votes.

Comment: @Silidrone would you care to enlighten us so that the rest of the forum might actually learn something the posts made over 10 years ago?

Comment: @WillNielsen There is a difference between making a table read-only and disabled. You can't select rows and it looks greyed out.

Answer (score 10):

If you are creating the TableModel automatically from a set of values (with "new JTable(Vector, Vector)"), perhaps it is easier to remove editors from columns:

```
JTable table = new JTable(my_rows, my_header);

for (int c = 0; c < table.getColumnCount(); c++)
{
    Class<?> col_class = table.getColumnClass(c);
    table.setDefaultEditor(col_class, null);        // remove editor
}
```

Without editors, data will be not editable.

Comment: -1 random hacking at inappropriated locations is _never_ an option

Comment: Please, can you explain why it is a "random hacking at inappropriated locations"? According to the [setDefaultEditor() doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultEditor%28java.lang.Class,%20javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor%29): "If editor is null, removes the default editor for this column class."

Comment: yeah, and falls back to the default for Object ;-) So you don't really disable editing (just accidentally if one of the columns is of type Object), also you are missing any columns that might have a custom editor. There _is_ api meant to be implemented to control cell editability, and that's the model's. Everything else is hacking and as such inappropriate.

Comment: I see your point. But what I understood from the api is that, if I create a table in the fast way (with "new JTable(Vector, Vector)"), then the table will have default editors for all of its columns. So, if I run "table.setDefaultEditor(column, null)", then I will remove the default editor from the column, so the column will not have any editor, and the column will not be editable. Will it be?

Comment: I'd created the table that way `new JTable(Vector, Vector)` and worked for me. I need no editor in no cell, so you have my vote.

Comment: so this work if we didn't add any custom editors for columns. and that would be the case most of the times. why would someone add custom editor and then disable it. only for one case that editing mode is getting enabled and disabled during app. journey. otherwise you are safe?!

Comment: A tweak on this approach allows for selective enable/disable edits by column.

Answer (score 4):

**I used this and it worked :** it is very simple and works fine.

```
JTable myTable = new JTable();
myTable.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Selection will not be possible.

Comment: Simple and nice Solution

Comment: Question is about editable not enabled.  Enable does not solve the purpose

Answer (score 2):

create new DefaultCellEditor class :

```
public static class Editor_name extends DefaultCellEditor {
  public Editor_name(JCheckBox checkBox) {
   super(checkBox);
  }
  @Override
  public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and use setCellEditor :

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.getColumn("columnName").setCellEditor(new Editor_name(new JCheckBox()));
```