How do I make a certain cells Uneditable in a jtable?
I want to make a cell that is uneditable if the data that it contains equals "VIDE". I searched for solutions but I couldn't find any.
Here is the method I want to edit:
private void UpdateTables(int id) throws Exception{
        
    DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel)ChosenGroupsTable.getModel();
    DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel)NotChosenGroupsTable.getModel();
    // Reset Tables
    model1.setRowCount(0);
    model2.setRowCount(0);
    
    List<EnrollsVO> enrollsList = new ArrayList<>();
    StudentsVO studentvo = StudentsDao.getInstance().getStudentByUserId(id);
    
    try {
        enrollsList = EnrollsDao.getInstance().loadAllStudentScreen(studentvo.getStudentID());
        //System.out.println("Number of groups retrieved from the database: " + enrollsList.size());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
        
    for(int i=0 ; i<enrollsList.size() ; i++){
        EnrollsVO enroll = enrollsList.get(i);
        Object[] rowData = new Object[8];
        rowData[0] = enroll.getEnrollID();
        rowData[1] = enroll.getCourse().getCourseName();
        rowData[2] = ResponsablesDao.getInstance().getResponsableByID(enroll.getCourse().getResponsable().getResponsableID()).getFirstName();
        rowData[3] = enroll.getSectionExam();
        if(enroll.getCourse().getCourse_TypeID() == 2 || enroll.getCourse().getCourse_TypeID() == 4){
            rowData[4] = enroll.getSectionTD();
        }else{
            rowData[4] = "VIDE";
           // System.out.println(enroll.getCourse().getCourse_TypeID());
        }
        if(enroll.getCourse().getCourse_TypeID() == 2 || enroll.getCourse().getCourse_TypeID() == 4){
            rowData[5] = enroll.getGroupeTD();
        }else{
            rowData[5] = "VIDE";
        }
        if(enroll.getCourse().getCourse_TypeID() == 3 || enroll.getCourse().getCourse_TypeID() == 4){
            rowData[6] = enroll.getSectionTP();
        }else{
            rowData[6] = "VIDE";
        }
        if(enroll.getCourse().getCourse_TypeID() == 3 || enroll.getCourse().getCourse_TypeID() == 4){
            rowData[7] = enroll.getGroupeTP();
        }else{
            rowData[7] = "VIDE";
        }
        
        // Check if all values from row 3 to row 7 are equal to 0
        boolean allZero = true;
        /*for (int j = 3; j <= 7; j++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(rowData[j].toString()) != 0) {
                allZero = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        // If all values from row 3 to row 7 are equal to 0, set rowData to "VIDE"
        if (allZero) {
            for (int j = 3; j <= 7; j++) {
                rowData[j] = "VIDE";
            }
        }
        */
        if (enroll.getSectionExam() != 0 && enroll.getSectionTD() != 0 && enroll.getGroupeTD()!= 0 && enroll.getSectionTP() != 0 && enroll.getGroupeTP()!= 0) {
    model1.addRow(rowData);
} else {
    model2.addRow(rowData);
}
}
    NotChosenGroupsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new GandSJInternalFrame.CustomCellRenderer());
    NotChosenGroupsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(new GandSJInternalFrame.CustomCellRenderer());
    NotChosenGroupsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setCellRenderer(new GandSJInternalFrame.CustomCellRenderer());
    NotChosenGroupsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setCellRenderer(new GandSJInternalFrame.CustomCellRenderer());
    NotChosenGroupsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setCellRenderer(new GandSJInternalFrame.CustomCellRenderer());
}

I tried using isCellEditable method and overriding it, and many other solutions.

Maybe this will help, if you did't try already ofcourse https://stackoverflow.com/a/36747065/17625629

Override the method isCellEditable

@Vled but like do u know where do i add that iscelleditable() method in my code?,

isCellEditable from the TableModel interface allows governing editability in a JTable.
The default table model of a JTable would be of class DefaultTableModel but the isCellEditable method in that class will always return true.
Your best bet is to subclass DefaultTableModel and have it make cells editable the way you want. Then set an instance of that subclass as the table model in your JTable.

I found a solution,even tho its not that good,basically i work with netbeans and when i create a table it automaticly intialize it in initcomp method,and i cant edit it unless i open the .java class in notepad so i just checked there and i think the iscelleditable there was overriding my iscelleditable so i just edited that iscelleditable to wut i want,but the problem now everytime i check the table in the design section of netbeans,it resets to wut it was before,this is just a school project i ll just keep it like this and hope no one will notice lol.
