# How to make the row editable(false) in JTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a JTable non-editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990817/how-to-make-a-jtable-non-editable)

I am developing an application using Netbeans.

I have generated a Report in a JTable format.

It works properly but the rows and colums are editable, and I would them to be non-editable.

Comment: By NetBeans, you mean the IDE or the platform? Either way, we don't really care for what you want to do I think. Also, do not prefix questions with "java:", tags are herer for this purpose. I took it upon me to rewrite bits of your question. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, and -1 because of lots of duplicates (see "related" section on the right) and answer is one google search away (and requested to be closed for both of these reasons).

Answer (score 4):

In your table model you can override the `isCellEditable()` method:

```
public class MyModel extends DefaultTableModel 
{
   public MyModel(Object[][] data, Object[] cols) 
   {
      super(data, cols);
   }

   public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) 
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: but I am useing Netbeans

Comment: @Jayashri I don't understand what you mean by that. Netbeans is a _Java_ IDE. What I posted is a Java class. Can you explain what you are having trouble with?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: He's used the GUI editor to create the table, and the default model is hard wired. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11456628/230513).

Comment: @trashgod Ok that makes more sense, I only saw 'I am using Netbeans' above which doesn't give me much to go on.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: +1 for using the model.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the NetBeans GUI editor to create your table. In the table's `Properties > model`, select the desired origin for the model. For example, you can add @Hunter's `Mymodel` to your source and choose `Custom code`:

```
new MyModel(data, cols)
```

[image: Custom Model]

Comment: @Jayashri: Note how the no-argument constructor fails. Also consider reducing your dependence on the GUI editor, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).