# How to change a table cell from editable to not editable with checkbox

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have created a jTable on an UI, where I want to change a cell attribute from editable to not editable according to other cell's boolean state (checkbox). I've been looking through several examples but failed to do what intended mainly because I made the mistake of creating the UI with NetBeans thus creating ton's of code which I can't even edit.

My Table: [table http://freepicupload.com/images/337jtable1.png](http://freepicupload.com/images/337jtable1.png)!

---

**EDIT: FIXED, working, code below.**

Code generating the table/model:

```
jTable1.setModel(new MyTableModel());
```

Table Model and the logic implemented:

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[] columnNames = {"Job Type",
                                    "Name",
                                    "avg Time",
                                    "Buffer",
                                    "Buffer Parts",
                                    "Color"};
    private Object[][] data = {
    {"1", "Station 1",
     new Integer(10), new Boolean(false), new Integer(0), Color.red},
    {"2", "Station 2",
     new Integer(10), new Boolean(false), new Integer(0), Color.blue},
    {"3", "Station 3",
     new Integer(10), new Boolean(false), new Integer(0), Color.green},
    {"4", "Station 4",
     new Integer(10), new Boolean(false), new Integer(0), Color.orange},
    {"5", "Station 5",
     new Integer(10), new Boolean(false), new Integer(0), Color.black}
    };

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    /*
     * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
     * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
     * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
     * rather than a check box.
     */
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * editable.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
        //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
        if (col == 0) { return false; }
        else if (col == 4) { 
            /*if (getValueAt(row,(col-1)) == "false") { System.out.println("NAO PODES EDITAR BOI"); }
            else if (getValueAt(row,(col-1)) == "true") { System.out.println("Podes que eu deixo!"); } */
            boolean di = (Boolean) getValueAt(row,(col-1));
            if (!di) { return false; }
            else { return true; }
        }
        else { return true; }
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * data can change.
     */
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    private void printDebugData() {
        int numRows = getRowCount();
        int numCols = getColumnCount();

        for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }
}
```

In this case, it will only allow to edit cells on column 4 if column 3's checkbox is checked (state true). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GUI editor creates a `DefaultTableModel` for you by default, but you can pry the model loose from the generated code by specifying `Custom code` for the relevant property, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456628/230513). Once you have control of the model, you can override `isCellEditable()` as required or as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513).

[image]

Comment: That I didn't know! Thank you very much, I will try and look at some examples to try and write a model that does what I need! Thank you!

Comment: I was able to use a custom model, but I came across with two small problems as stated on my edited initial question, mind taking a look?

Comment: Override `getColumnClass()` as shown in the original generated code or in the second example cited above.

Comment: That fixed the checkbox problem, but I'm still getting and exception when its state changes:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at SimGui$1.actionPerformed(SimGui.java:167)

Being 166,167:

    boolean b = Boolean.parseBoolean(String.valueOf(tcl.getNewValue()));
    table1model.setColumnEditable(tcl.getColumn(), b);

Comment: The GUI is still using a custom editor; use the [default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: I am sorry, but could you explain?

Comment: I believe there is no way to make a cell editable/non-editable but just the whole column?!

Comment: No, `isCellEditable()` controls each cell; the default editor is based on column class; please read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) cited, and edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) if you still have problems.

Comment: Thank you. I was taking a wrong approach, I read everything and started with the default model and worked my way up and now it works.

Fixed code on my question. Thanks a lot!