# Change row color of Jtable row when user clicks

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, listselectionlistener

Below is the code i used to generate table data using JTable

```
public class Scroller extends JFrame {

    public Scroller() throws HeadlessException {

            String columnNames[] = { "Location", "Lived In People" };

            // Create some data
            String dataValues[][] =
            {
                { "100 Hamilton", "" },
                { "", "Balan" },
                { "", "Kris" },
                { "Parkwood place", "" },
                { "", "Kris" }
            };

        JTable table = new JTable(dataValues, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 600));

        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(50);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Scroller().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The output looks like below

[image]

Now, i can able to click on each row. But when i double click any cell, it lets me edit the
data in the cell. I found i can use `table.setEnabled(false)` to make this not to happen.

But i am trying to make the table so that, each row can be selected but the cells should not be editable. is there any straight forward method to achieve this?

**NOTE :** I tried to override the function `isCellEditable` as specified in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990817/how-to-make-a-jtable-non-editable#answer-3134006). But when running the screen shows only empty table.

Comment: comment to your edit, DefaultTableModel has the same constructor, like as JTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a TableModel, which implements isCellEditable by always returning true. Your desired behaviour can be achieved by writing a Table Model that always returns false.
Example:

```
public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

 public MyTableModel(Vector data, Vector columnNames) {
    setDataVector(data, columnNames);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
         return false;
     }
}
```

and add this line to your code:

```
table.setModel(new MyTableModel(data, columnNames));
```

**Alternative**

If you wanna stick to the double array, try:

```
JTable table = new JTable(new AbstractTableModel() {
            public String getColumnName(int column) { return columnNames[column].toString(); }
            public int getRowCount() { return dataValues.length; }
            public int getColumnCount() { return columnNames.length; }
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { return dataValues[row][col]; }
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) { return false; }
        });
```

For that to work, you will need to make your variables `columnNames` and `dataValues` **`final`**.

Comment: I tried this, but after setting the model, i cannot see any data in the table. Its loaded empty.

Comment: I also posted an answer without noticing this answer. This is correct. But you'll also need to override getValueAt() in the model and return those data values from it.

Comment: ah right, you need to call setDataVector(data, columnNames) in the constructor;

Comment: i tried to define the Vector for data and columns like Vector<String>, but it shows error like `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector`.. how should i define vector for this format?

Comment: I added an alternative for the double array. Vector is not ideal, because it is a bit outdated. If the array is not enough for you, try the tutorials here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data , they give you a good idea how to create a table model using a list of objects.

Comment: I got the way to implement vector.. thanks for the valuable answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

answer to first of 5-6 potentials points

```
i cannot see any data in the table. Its loaded empty
```

- please see API for [DeafultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

code example (everything there is declared as local variables)

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;
    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
        "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian", "Date"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), (false), new Date()},
        {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), (true), new Date()},
        {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), (false), null},
        {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), (true), new Date()},
        {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), (false), new Date()},};
    private TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            switch (col) {
                case 1:
                    return true;
                case 3:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    };

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        frame.add(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom table model (you'll have to embed the data values in it and override getValueAt method to return those), then override its isCellEditable() to return false.