# How to edit cell in jtable

Tags: java, jtable

I'm doing a project that requires Jtable. However I'm using 3 Jtables. How am I able to make the third table cell editable while the first 2 remain uneditable?

The first 2 table are in a same Jpanel, while the third table on the other hand is on another Jpanel.

Here is my code for my FoodTableModel :

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return true;
}   

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    data[row][col] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
```

Comment: Always a good read: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a flag in your custom table model, and use it like

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){

    if(cellEditable) {   
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990817/how-to-make-a-jtable-non-editable) answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will take note. mind if i ask another question? How do i validate the input such that it will only contain integer only?

Comment: Add a validation at the beginning of the `setValueAt` method.